# macOS Window Overlay Effect Bug?

Tags: swift, macos, autolayout, appkit

EDIT: I still have not gotten this to work. Would someone mind downloading my simple test project and trying it on their machine? There's just boilerplate code and a storyboard.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qtoqhi7pjq5w3hh/AADLCTY_7FPG18RWeSe57Jroa?dl=0

ORIGINAL QUESTION: I’m developing a macOS app for Big Sur. I want to take advantage of the blur effect of the window bar over my content. I have set the `fullSizeContentView` mask on the window. However, I can only get the effect to work when I have set a minimal amount of spacing between the scrollview’s leading edge and its superview’s leading edge. This seems to be a bug in AppKit. Can anyone confirm or tell me what I’m doing wrong?

See below clips:
First I have a simple Xcode project (no code, just using the Storyboard). Scroll view is setup in the content view of the view controller. The Scroll View has no spacing to its superview for its top, trailing and bottom edges. The leading edge has standard spacing (20pt) to its superview’s leading edge.
[image: blur works as expected]

This works as expected, but I don’t want the the leading edge spacing. So I set the leading edge spacing to 0.
[image: set leading edge spacing to 0]

And the blur effect goes away.
[image: no blur :(]

Comment: What happens if you set the leading spacing to 1? 0.5? 0.1? In other words, can you find the specific value that makes the behavior change?

Comment: Yes, 1pt seems to be the threshold at which the behavior changes.

Comment: Sounds like a macOS bug

Comment: Does the blur effect show up if it's set to -1?

Comment: It does! I've done some more testing, and it seems the leading edge spacing range of -0.3 to 0.8, exclusive, is what AppKit doesn't like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: It seems that this 'issue' has been fixed in macOS 12 beta 5.

The code below may still be useful for macOS 11.

---

Nowadays macOS is overcrowded with small weird 'issues' and this seems to be one of them. In most cases these issues are only solvable by applying weird solutions, because we don't have access to the inner parts of AppKit.

```
if let constraint = view.constraints.first(where: { $0.firstAttribute == .leading }) {
   constraint.constant = -0.3
}
```

Applying a small negative leading constraint seems to solve the problem for now. Can be done in code, and theoretically also in the Storyboard, although it's hard to enter and store decimal values in interface designer.

Comment: Is this the sort of thing that Apple will fix in the next version of AppKit? I imagine I'm not the only one that has encountered this issue.

Comment: @user1922718 I wouldn't hold my breath for that. Always start with filing a bug report in Feedback Assistant, and include your sample project. If you have unused Technical Support Incidents, the you can consider to use one to ask for confirmation if this is indeed a bug.